# Popular Chart.JS com dados do MySQL passado no render da página por uma função async

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js, chartjs

Fala pessoal, estou querendo popular um gráfico de pizza na minha página dashboard, porém não estou conseguindo, podem me ajudar *(Não quero usar php, somente javascript, jquery e html)*.

- Gráfico: Chart.JS
- BD: MySQL
- Linguagem: Javascript / Node.JS

**Minha rota na qual passo o Json no render da página:**

```
pageAdmin: (req, res) => {
  (async function () {
    let teste = await DBModel.getTeste();

    res.render('./pageAdmin', {
       //Dados que são passados para a página
       DTTeste: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(teste))
    });

  })();//async
};
```

**Aqui meu arquivo ejs onde renderizo o gráfico (front-end):**

```
<div class="row">
   <div style="padding:10px" id="chart-container">
        <canvas id="pie-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
   </div>
</div>
```

**E por fim o trecho que contém o script para gerar e popular o gráfico:**

```
<script>
    new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart"), {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Population (millions)",
                backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f", "#e8c3b9", "#c45850"],
                data: [2478, 5267, 734, 784, 433]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Como faço para popular o label e data do gráfico utilizando o "DTTeste" recebido no render?**

Os dados estão vindo desta forma (olhando no console.log):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**onde "status"_rnc será a label do gráfico e "Qtde" será os valores**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código com a solução:

```
<!-- Pizza total peças por perfil no dia -->
<script>

    //Variáveis que receberão os dados para popular o gráfico
    const linhaProducao = [];
    const pecasProduzidas = [];

    //Dados recebidos do res.render na rota
    '<% DTTotalPecasPorPerfil.forEach((row, index) => { %>'
        linhaProducao.push('<%- row.Perfil %>');
        pecasProduzidas.push('<%- row.Total %>');
    '<% }); %>'

    //Doughnut chart definido no canvas da página
    //var ctx = document.getElementById('pie-chart').getContext('2d');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('pie-chart');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //Iniciando o gráfico
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',//Tipo de gráfico
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        responsive: true,
        data: {
            labels: linhaProducao,//Texto agrupador
            datasets: [{
                data: pecasProduzidas,//Valores
                backgroundColor: ["#007bff", "#ffc107", "#28a745", "#702CA1"],//Cores
                borderWidth: 0.9,
                borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: false,
                text: 'Titulo aqui',
                position: 'top',
                fontSize: 16,
                fontColor: '#000000',
                padding: 20,
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true,
                animateRotate: true,
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
                labels: {
                    size: 14,
                    lineHeight: 1.6,
                    boxWidth: 20,
                    fontColor: '#181B22',
                    padding: 12,
                }
            },
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
            },
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    font: {
                        size: 14,
                        weight: 'bold',
                        lineHeight: 1.6,
                    },
                    formatter: function (value, ctx) {
                        //return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex] + '\n' + value;
                        return value;
                    }
                }
            },
        },
    });
</script>
```